# How to draw only selected borders on a control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am building a custom control and I need it to only paint the top border. How can it be done?

**Edit:** Currently I am using this code:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.DesignMode)
    {
        Rectangle bounds = this.ClientRectangle;
        GraphicsPath topEdge = new GraphicsPath();
        topEdge.StartFigure();
        topEdge.AddLine(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.X + bounds.Width, bounds.Y);
        topEdge.CloseFigure();
        e.Graphics.DrawPath(new Pen(SystemColors.ActiveBorder, 1), topEdge);
    }
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

This works well when there are no nested controls inside my custom control. Once I start to add controls, they seem to over-draw the border line.

Comment: could draw a line I guess

Comment: @sa_ddam213: Thanks for the comment. That's what I am doing. But the lines are over-drawn by other controls inside my custom control. So I need a foolproof way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [ControlPaint.DrawBorder Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawborder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From this article [Draw a Border around any C# Winform Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/388405/Draw-a-Border-around-any-Csharp-Winform-Control): the following adds a border around a control:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnPaint(e);
  ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle,
                            Color.Black, BORDER_SIZE, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                            Color.Black, BORDER_SIZE, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                            Color.Black, BORDER_SIZE, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset,
                            Color.Black, BORDER_SIZE, ButtonBorderStyle.Inset);
}
```